# Two to the power of some large number

Tags: c, modular-arithmetic

Can anyone tell me how to find (2^101100111000)%1000000007 in C? 
There is a problem in which we have to convert a number into binary(1<=N<=600000) and find 
2^(binary representation of N)modulo1000000007.

Comment: Use a big number arithmetic library?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation. Binary is merely a representation, so it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Many, many duplicates, e.g. [What is the fastest way to compute large power of 2 modulo a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289495/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-large-power-of-2-modulo-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

The values you are talking about will not fit into a standard long on any architecture, so you will have to use an arbitrary precision maths library such as [***GMP***](http://gmplib.org/).

Hmm, just read [***Zong's***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1473751/zong-zheng-li) answer... he's pointing to a more efficient method... haven't finished reading through the article but it looks like the better way to go...

Comment: No, this is the wrong approach. You don't need to actually calculate such large values.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi not the wrong approach the inefficient one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting... looks like I'm learning too :)