# 1 left shift by n

Tags: c, bit-shift

in this equation

```
#define mod 1000000007
int n;
int num = ((1<<n)%mod)+2;
```

I have to left shift 1 by any value of n and then perform mod operation to contain the result within the range of int. But the `1<<n` is not showing correct value for bigger values of n such as 1000 or 10000. How to do it ?

Comment: It does not give correct output because after 31 shifts overflow happens

Comment: Related (possibly even a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289495/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-large-power-of-2-modulo-a-number

Answer (score 2):

The maximum you can left-shift `1` by is `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 2`. Any larger amount causes undefined behaviour.

If you want to work with numbers like 2<sup>10000</sup> you are going to have to use a big integer library (or write your own) , there are no built-in data types that can handle that sort of number accurately.

Another option is to use a smarter algorithm for modular exponentiation.